# Появляются лишние символы ' , ) при отправке в сообщения данных из sqlite; telebot

Tags: python, sqlite, telebot

Пишу телеграм бота-магазин. Столкнулся с проблемой что после парсинга из sqlite базы и отправке результата появляются лишние скобки, запятые и апострафы. Вот код:

```
        elif message.text == "данные от киви":
            conn = sqlite3.connect("base_ts.sqlite")
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            login = cursor.execute('SELECT login FROM qiwi')
            row = cursor.fetchall()
            token = cursor.execute('SELECT token FROM qiwi')
            raw = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            text1 = ''
            text2 = ''
            text1 = text1 + 'номер: ' + str(row[0])
            bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=f'{text1}')
            text2 = text2 + 'токен: ' + str(raw[0])
            bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=f'{text2}')
```

Результат бота:

```
номер: ('39847474303',)

токен: ('1kkemeldp03333',)
```

Желательный результат:

```
номер: 39847474303

токен: 1kkemeldp03333
```

Comment: похоже что вам прилетает кортеж (скорей всего), а сам `fetcall()` возвращает список кортежей. Может вот так будет валидно: `row[0][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменить row[0] на row[0][0] в строках text1 и text2